# Create a "message" on a duplicate

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a duplicate system, except that I don't can display an error message which explains to the user that there is a duplicate.

I only have the message to add a data in fact...

[image]

```
public function store(dateRequest $request)
{   
       $exists = Student::where('name', $request->get('name'))
           ->where('firstname', $request->get('firstname'))
           ->count();

       if (!$exists){
            Student::create($request->all());
        }

        return redirect()
            ->route('students.index')
            ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');

}
```

Comment: So you want to return a message like "Record already exists" if student exists ?

Comment: @Yash Malla: Yes, sorry ...

Comment: You have an `if` statement that checks if it doesn't exist, maybe add an `else { ... }` and do something if it already does?

Comment: @Tim Lewis: I have tried this but it doesn't work: `if (!$exists){
            Student::create($request->all());
        }
        
        else{
            session()->flash('error', 'doublon !!');
        }`

Comment: You still have to `redirect()` though; `session()->flash()` on it's own doesn't do that.

Comment: @Tim Lewis: Thank you it works !! :-) Here is the code `if (!$exists){
            Student::create($request->all());
            return redirect()->route('students.index')
                ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
        }

        else{
            return redirect()->route('students.index')
                ->with('success', 'doublon');

        } `

Comment: No problem! Feel free to add that as your own answer; it's not doing anyone any good being in the comments :)

Comment: @Tim Lewis: Indeed, I have edited my first message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$exists` has the number of rows, so you can simply check if it's greater than `0` and then act accordingly:

```
public function store(dateRequest $request)
{
  // Returns the number of rows
  $exists = Student::where('name', $request->get('name'))->where('firstname', $request->get('firstname'))->count();

  // Check if there's a row
  if($exists > 0) {
    // Record exists, redirect with the error message
    return redirect()->route('students.index')->with('error', 'Record already exists!');
  }

  // Record doesn't exist, create it
  Student::create($request->all());

  // Redirect with success message
  return redirect()->route('students.index')->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
}
```

> Note: The solution given in the comments, sends the error message as a success message, thus making it appear as a green bar, which is something that **I personally** wouldn't want an 'error' message to look like.

To make the styling change based on the type of message that you send with the redirect, use something like this:

```
@if(count($errors) > 0)
  @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
          {{$error}}
      </div>
  @endforeach
@endif

@if(session('success'))
  <div class="alert alert-success">
      {{session('success')}}
  </div>
@endif

@if(session('error'))
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
     {{session('error')}}
  </div>
@endif
```

Add the blade code above in a separate blade file, which you can then include wherever you need the error, or success messages to appear.

---

You can then use this to send an error, with a red bar:

```
return redirect()->route('students.index')->with('error', 'Error message');
```

And use this code to send a success message, with a green bar:

```
return redirect()->route('students.index')->with('success', 'Success message');
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't see the error message for "the record already exists"

Comment: Could you show the blade code that you use for the messages?

Comment: the friend Lewis has a solution public function `store(dateRequest $request)
    {      
       $exists = Student::where('name', $request->get('name'))->where('firstname', $request->get('firstname'))->count();

       if (!$exists){
            Student::create($request->all());
            return redirect()->route('students.index')
                ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
        }

        else{
            return redirect()->route('students.index')
                ->with('success', 'doublon');

        }   

    }`

Comment: Okay, but I assume that you're so called 'error' message will appear as green?

Comment: yeess, How Can I change the color to red please?

Comment: I added a snippet of blade code that will automatically change the alert color to danger when you send an error, notice the `->with('error', 'message')` instead of `->with('success', 'message')`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code

```
public function store(dateRequest $request){   
           $exists = Student::where('name', $request->get('name'))->where('firstname', $request->get('firstname'))->count();

           if (!$exists){
                Student::create($request->all());
                 return redirect()->route('students.index')
                                  ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
            } else {
                 return redirect()->route('students.index')
                                  ->with('fail', 'User with that name already exists');
            }

}
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't see the error message for "the record already exists"

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

```
public function store(dateRequest $request)
    {      
       $exists = Student::where('name', $request->get('name'))->where('firstname', $request->get('firstname'))->count();

       if (!$exists){
            Student::create($request->all());
            return redirect()->route('students.index')
                ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
        }

        else{
            return redirect()->route('students.index')
                ->with('success', 'doublon');

        }   

    }
```